# login.aspx was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I originally created a ASP.NET MVC4 project using the wrong authentication/template in Visual Studio. So I've been trying to make it use windows authentication (I already changed the project property to enable it) but there was a bunch of built-in garbage in my project:

```
- AccountController
- AuthConfig.RegisterAuth() im my Global.asax.cs
- AccountModel.cs
```

... and some other crap that I can't remember at this point

I went through and deleted all that junk but I still get the following error:

```
Error Page 404: The controller for path '/login.aspx' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

So it mentions some ASPX page in my ASP.NET MVC project that doesn't even exist. It would appear as though I didn't thoroughly go through and remove every reference to the "built-in" authentication login garbage that was put into the project when I first created it.

Can anyone provide any insight?

Comment: Did you check your default route? It might be still pointing to your old controller method which was automatically mapped during your project creation

Comment: Anything in the webconfig?

Comment: No. I've searched for "login" and ".aspx" in my entire solution and there are no results.

Comment: Has anyone been able to figure this out? I'm experiencing the same thing.